# cannot access manage attributes magento

Tags: php, database, magento, nginx, server-error

My magento admin part works as it supposed to do, but when i want to access catalog - MANAGE ATTRIBUTES i get 500 Server error... I can access my attribute sets and i have all my attributes but i cant manage them...

I imported db from live site where everything worked. I had problem with premissions when uploading imgs so i changed all to read, write, execute and that fixed the problem, but this 500 is giving me a headache.

I would be greatfull for any thought, maybe is something stupid. Magento is new world for me, sorry, please understand

Comment: This question is more appropriate for Server Fault. Here it is likely to be flagged as “Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault” and closed.

Comment: @sideshowbarker but this question involves a PHP framework - it's also probably a code problem. Smiljanic - have you checked your nginx error logs, and the Magento logs?

Comment: @RobbieAverill ah OK, thanks for the clarification—it wasn’t clear to me from the question itself nor the tags. So I’ve added the `php` and `nginx` tags to try to help make it more clear. Feel free to change or remove those if you think they’re not actually necessary.

Comment: check your magento logs.

Comment: Thanks guys! Log saved my ass! One file was mising, deep deep in code (dont know why, it was copy/paste)...
app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Block\Adminhtml\Attribute\Grid\Abstract.php

Works good now!